# Socket.IO connection attempt is blocking browser behavior

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I was attempting to use a small .gif image in the center of my screen as a indicator that the page was loading while the application attempted to connect to the server. This was just for testing purposes as my current testing machine is really slow, but I wanted to make sure that users that had slow connections weren't staring at nothing while forming a connection.

I was greeted with a frozen .gif image. It didn't move. That is, until the connection was established, then it dissapeared. (Which, don't get me wrong, it was supposed to upon connection establishment). So I disabled that. To my suprise once the connection was established the gif played flawlessly.

Socket.IOs documentation is really bad, I don't even think you can call it a documentation, so I'm trying to figure out the best way to go about fixing this issue. I thought node bragged about only allowing completely asynchronous modules to be added to the package list. This seems like it's blocking to me.

Connection being established through

```
var socket = io('http://xx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx');
```

The whole idea of a loading indicator is pretty boring if it's a static one, I mean I can make a static loading indicator, but it's just boring. You don't see any progress. You don't really feel like anything is happening. There's something about things moving on the screen that make you feel like you're making some progress.

Comment: Something else could be the issue. Post the rest of the code.

Comment: @laggingreflex - This was tested with ONLY the .GIF image and the connection code, Nothing more, nothing less.